# How do you locate a battery drain?

Tags: battery, electrical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery drains by itself when vehicle is parked (parasitic draw)](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/91/battery-drains-by-itself-when-vehicle-is-parked-parasitic-draw)

Something is leaching current from my battery. Leaving it parked for a few days results in the battery being almost too weak to start the car. I can leave a trickle charger attached, but I want to find the source of the problem.