# Battery Draw while car is off at 3.24

Tags: electrical, battery, saab, battery-drain

I have a 2007 Saab 95 wagon...  For about 6 months at random about once a month my car has been dead. After calling AAA and they told me there is a draw from the battery at apx 3.24 which is should be much lower. 3 weeks ago I took it to the mechanic he kept it for 6 days and played the guess and check game with the wiring and fuses... Eventually he ended up swapping out my battery for a new one... I had AAA come back and re test and the car is still reading 3.24. Any suggestions on what this could be.

~~I know it is not the alternator or the actual battery

My next guess is to just unplug the alarm (which I don't use)

Helppp!!! I love my car and don't want to get rid of it.

Comment: It's drawing 3.24 amps when it's off?

Comment: If you want to troubleshoot this yourself, you can pick up an inexpensive amp meter to measure the battery draw.  It might stink having to buy a tool that you might not use often, but it will be cheaper than having someone else look at it, and it's easy.   If you're willing to try, the procedure is to measure the current draw on the battery while you pull each fuse from the fuse box.  We can help with more details!

Comment: Your question is basically a duplicate of [this previous question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/91/12030).

Comment: I'd like to add that an inductive ammeter would be preferable so that you don't reset any computer circuits that may be causing the draw.

Comment: This answer describes a good start: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/357/13641

Comment: 3.24 what? 3.24 amperes, 3.24 milliamperes, 3.24 potatoes?

Comment: 3milliamp is normal. have you had a problem with the new battery?

Comment: Maybe some wire(s) are draining the battery. This problem had the car of my father. The wires from the tail lights broke and got grounded at the trunk hinges, caused a short circuit and the battery was completly empty after a while. Maybe there is a broken wire somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a Parasitic Draw Test. Test each of the fuses to see if any one or more than one fuse is draining power or causing a current drop to occur. Also you can test the fuse w/o having to remove each individual fuse. Just touch the leads to the contacts on the top of each fuse.