# Amplifier is causing battery drain

Tags: electrical, battery, alternator, audio, drain

Okay I'm driving a 1998 Honda Civic EX and I have an audio system in my car that is about 7-8 years old now.

I had done some work on one of the terminals on the subwoofers, and melted plastic in between the terminals as an insulator. After about a month, my CD player started flickering on and off again, as it does nearly every winter, which also happens during heavy humidity or rain, because there are some air leaks in my car as I have wrecked it a few times.

So far I have replaced the alternator belt, the battery, and the headlight switch. We fixed the headlights a while back, and I ended up hitting these pot holes strewn across I-40 around Knoxville, TN, jarring something once again.

I'm certain that the battery drain is directly connected to moisture but even after unplugging my main fuse for my subs coming from the battery, and disconnecting the faceplate (which works on dry days/nights at work). My problem is that my car battery dies while it is turned off for 8+ hours but not while it is running.

Once the power is disconnected, power shouldn't be able to drain, unless there is something physically broken and touching in the cd player, however, without the ignition on, there shouldn't be any currents at all. I have a ticket from the city I live in and a city I recently visited and I'm supposed to have it repaired in about 9 days. What could be causing the issue?

Also if I disconnect the battery for about 30 seconds, the cd player will forget that it was messed up, and turn on again, until I turn the volume up to high, at which point it will flicker to the point of just shutting off.

Note: The head lights are not related.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/91/12030

Comment: I think it could be that your amplifier is too powerful for your car's electrical system. You could try finding a higher capacity battery, a more powerful alternator, or adding some capacitors to the amplifier wiring.

Comment: It's always been fine but if the car is not running it will kill the battery in around 30 minutes or more.

Comment: One possibility is a faulty connection to the head unit and/or amplifier.  Check the constant power lines and the remote wire which goes to the amp signaling on or off. Depending on how your head unit is wired, if the system can be turned on without the key this may be an issue

Answer (score 3):

are you running an amplifies for the subs?  if yes are you using a capacitor in line with the power to the amp and have you check the voltage to the amps signal on wire?  As the deck also receives power from a direct source of the battery to retain memory. the deck could be damaged (possibly also directly affected by moisture) and unless you are disconnecting one of the battery terminals it is possible that a damaged deck is still providing voltage to the signal wire of the amp hense causing a voltage drain regardless that the face plate of the Deck is attached or not.  just a thought and a possibility to your issue.

Comment: Well last night there was no moisture and it was perfectly fine all night and started when I got off work, I also noticed that the battery terminal was disconnected on one side.. So you've got to be right.. I guess I'm gonna need a new CD player. Yes I have a Kicker kx 350.2 bridgeable. I do not have a capacitor installed

Comment: @GettingNifty did you try disconnecting the amplifier? The amp has a connection for a remote wire. When 12V is passed from the CD player the amplifier is turned on. If the player is malfunctioning and staying on constantly then it can keep the amp on as well. If the drain slows down after disconnecting the amp voltage wire then this is definitely the case.

Comment: So far it's been starting fine I've just taken the main fuse out and left the faceplate off.. Should I connect the face plate and see if it drains?

Comment: No, i think you safe to say that you have identity the issue.  Just replace the deck and get  capacitor for the amp main power line in.