# battery in a 2000 jeep grand

Tags: battery, jeep, charging

I have  a battey problem with my 2000 Jeep grand cherkoee can't keep the battery charged I have replaced the after market headlites and also had to replace the heater resistor but am at a lose as to why the battery won't stay charged

Comment: Welcome to the site. Have you had the charging system checked? If the alternator is not working, it will not charge the battery.

Comment: It is also possible that the battery is nearing the end of its useful lifetime, meaning you need a jump start every time (in fact, if the battery is severely damaged, a jump start may damage the car electronics when disconnecting the jumper cables).

Answer (score 2):

Several possibilities I know of:

1. **Old battery.**  This is the most likely IMO.  When the battery gets old, it no holds its charge.  See [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/406/how-do-i-test-my-car-battery) for more details on battery testing.
2. **Corrosion on Battery leads.** Unlikely, but corrosion could actually be causing a energy leak, meaning that the battery can't deliver current like it should.  Check to make sure you have a solid connection on your battery
3. **Parasitic drain.**  There could be a parasitic drain on your car's system.  Check out [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/91/battery-drains-by-itself-when-vehicle-is-parked-parasitic-draw) for more info on parasitic draws.

Hope you can nail your problem and get it fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check for any device / circuit using energy while the motor is off. Possible culprits include the diodes in the alternator, glove box or interior lights not turning off or even the radio...